# editor length validation xamarin forms

Tags: validation, xaml, xamarin, editor

I would like to do some validation to this editor , for example "editor can not be empty write something". I could validate as input < 0 , however, I will need this validation in order to go to the next page . Any ideas ? Thanks. 
this is my xaml.

```
     <StackLayout Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                        <Label Text="Description" FontSize="Medium" Style="{StaticResource LabelStyle}" />
                        <Editor x:Name="Description" FontSize="Medium" HeightRequest="120" TextChanged ="Handle_TextChanged" />
<Label x:Name ="Errorlabel"/>
                    </StackLayout>
```

cs:

```
 async void Send_Activated(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var editor = EDescription.Text;

            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace (editor))
            {
                Errorlabel.Text = "Plase add a description ";
                ToolbarItems.Clear();

            }

            if (editor.Length >1)
            {
                await App.Navigator.PushAsync(new 2View());  
            }
      }
```

toolbar :

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem  x:Name = "anySend" Text="Send" Order="Primary" Activated="Send_Activated"  />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a simple way to validate for non-null entries:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Description.Text)) {
    DisplayAlert("Error","Please enter a description", "OK");
} else {
    Navigation.PushAsync(nextPage);
}
```

Xamarin also has an extensive writeup on doing [Validation in MVVM](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/enterprise-application-patterns/validation/)

Comment: Thank you Jason! I add your example , but when I click next on the toolbar . it returns not object found.~ please see the update ~

Comment: error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: you might need to explicitly check for "editor == null"

Comment: Thanks . thats should do it . keep you posted

Comment: FluentValidation has a simple built-in rule for NotEmpty - I like the style of it and based on the article Jason linked to, created a library to make working with FluentValidation and Xamarin very simple - check it out here (complete with an example): https://github.com/mzhukovs/FluentValidationRulesPlugin